# MVC Core DateTimePicker not showing up in dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show the datetimepicker box in the table which is created dynamically, here's my code.

```
<body>
        <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <select id="NumOfRow" name="NumOfRow" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                    </select>
                                   <input id="DateOfBirth" type="text" /> // this one is working
                        <div id="adTable"></div>
    </div>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            yearRange: "-77:+00"
        });
        $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker("option", "showAnim", "clip");

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#NumOfRow').change(function () {
                CreateTable();
            });
        });

        function CreateTable() {
            $('#adTable').empty();
            var x = $('#NumOfRow').val();
            var data = '';
            var complete = '';
            var y = 2;
            for (i = 1; i < x; i++) {

                data = '<table>' +
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td>' +
                    'Vessel Name' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td>' +
                    '<input id="Name" type="text"/>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td> Date Of Birth </td>' +
                    '<td><input id="datetimepick" type="text"/></td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '</table>';    
                y += 1;
                complete += data;

                $("#datetimepick").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                    yearRange: "-77:+00"
                });
                $("#datetimepick").datepicker("option", "showAnim", "clip");    
            }
            $('#adTable').append(complete);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

The table can be generated without any problem, however, the datetimepicker won't shows up in the input that is being generated dynamically.
Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it after you append also you cannot add multiple datetimepicker to an ID, you should make it a class instead

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <select id="NumOfRow" name="NumOfRow" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <input id="DateOfBirth" type="text" /> // this one is working
    <div id="adTable"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- edit: Try with these cdn's if you're not sure your src's are correct -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

JQUERY

```
$("#DateOfBirth").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
  yearRange: "-77:+00"
});
$("#DateOfBirth").datepicker("option", "showAnim", "clip");

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#NumOfRow').change(function() {
    CreateTable();
  });
});

function CreateTable() {
  $('#adTable').empty();
  var x = $('#NumOfRow').val();
  var data = '';
  var complete = '';
  var y = 2;
  for (i = 1; i < x; i++) {

    data = '<table>' +
      '<tr>' +
      '<td>' +
      'Vessel Name' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td>' +
      '<input id="Name" type="text"/>' +
      '</td>' +
      '</tr>' +
      '<tr>' +
      '<td> Date Of Birth </td>' +
      '<td><input class="datetimepick" type="text"/></td>' +
      '</tr>' +
      '</table>';
    y += 1;
    complete += data;

  }
  $('#adTable').append(complete);
  $(".datetimepick").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    yearRange: "-77:+00"
  });
  $(".datetimepick").datepicker("option", "showAnim", "clip");
}
```

JSFIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/gmuwpytz/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I follow exactly like what you did and the JsFiddle proven to be working. But it is still not showing on my page. Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: @Krayon2 could you try putting the jquery and jquery.ui libraries in the header? tell me if that works. If that's the problem I can show you how to do it in the body as well

Comment: @Krayon2 I tried loading jquery and jquery ui like you did in the body, and it seems to be working as well. Are you sure the `src` 's are correct?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still not working. the src should be correct because once I delete it, the id="DateOfBirth" which is not in the dynamically generated table won't show the datetimepicker as well.

Comment: @Krayon2 that's true, is there maybe some css that doesn't let it display? maybe some kind of z-index or position?

Comment: thanks for the fast response. But there's no bootstrap at the moment. I run the console and had this error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at CreateTable (Test2:111)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (Test2:80)
    at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4732)
    at HTMLSelectElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4544)

What do you think? Much appreciated of your time

Comment: It might be from the CSS also. Do you know how to disable the navigation that came initially? I have removed the _NavLayout but there's still navigation

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. You are correct, it is with the CSS. I disable the layout by having @{
    Layout = null;
}, Then it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: Oh my Gosh though. Do you know how I could find the problem with the CSS?

Comment: @Krayon2 right click > inspect element and try to check and uncheck some css attributed (Chrome) and see what's working. I suggest adding position:relative; and z-index:99; or more (999)

Comment: @Krayon2 if you can't find the css file, just make your own and add the !important tag like: `position:relative !important;`

Comment: add the position: relative to where exactly?